# Do Slime Molds Rot?

Tags: nethack

I couldn't find this information on the wiki. I found a slime mold lying around and have absolutely no other source of nutrition. I'd like to hold on to it until I'm starving, but I don't know if it'll rot or not (if it does, I'll just eat it immediately).

Does a slime mold rot?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Slime molds](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Slime_mold) are actually a kind of fruit, like apples or melons, and are not corpses. Like other non-corpse comestibles, they won't rot away.

As a point of interest, the only corpses that never rot away are lichen and lizards.

Comment: Really? I was pretty sure I had eaten rotten apples before.

Comment: Yes, the food itself can be [intrinsically rotten](http://nethack.wikia.com/wiki/Comestible#Rotten_food.5B1.5D). But that's not the same as *rotting away*.